# How set user as Log on as batch in Windows 10 Home version?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security-policy

I need to set a user as "Log on as batch" to run a program in Task Scheduler.
I need to open up the secpol.msc but this program at "Run" does not exist in my windows 10 home version. This only exist in Pro and Enterprise version. Any alternative ways to set that user right ? Thanks